# changing the price depending on the size and showing the size

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have been trying to do this for days but I can't seems to make it work.
I want to change the price depending on the shoe size the user selected. But I NEED TO KNOW WHAT SIZE THE CHOOSE on the checkout.php. My checkout.php is already working but I need to get the size and also the prize for that size. In the select options i have indicate the prices and what size the price is for.Please help.

```
<div class="content_half float_r">
    <form id="add2cart" name="cart" method="Post" action="<?php fetchdir($bpages); ?>cart.php">
             <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="160">Price:</td>
                        <td name="price" id="price"><?php echo $row ['Start_Cost']; ?></td>

                    </tr>

                <tr>
                 <td for="size" width="160">size*:</td>
                <td>
                <select name="size" class="small" id ="size">
                                <option value="">12 size</option> // the price tag already have the start_Cost for this size
                        <option value="">14 size(£30.00)</option>
                    <option value="">16 size(£35.00)</option>
                        <option value="">18 size(£40.00)</option>
                    <option value="">20 size(£45.00)</option>
                        <option value="">22 size(£55.00)</option>
                            <option value="">24 size(£60.00)</option>
                    <option value="">26 size(70.00)</option>
                            <option value="">28 size(£80.00)</option>
                   </select>
                </td>

                </tr>   
        <tr>
             // you choose size
            <td> size: // the size the person choose will go down here
             </td>

    </tr>   

            <tr>
                        <td>Quantity</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Qty" value="1" style="width: 20px; text-align: right" /></td>

                    </tr>       
                </table>    
                <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <input type="Submit" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add to shopping cart"/>
                </form>             
            </div>
```

Comment: If your `value` attributes of the `<option>` elements are empty, then you won't pass anything back to the backend.  You need something in those `value=""`.  The text contents of the `<option>` are only for display purposes.

Comment: put the size price in the `option value`?

Comment: I want to pass the size to the backend and on the price i want to pass the price for that size to the backend.  I tried it before in the value=""  it was value="£30.00" for size 14 but i kept passing the £30.00 which i dont want but instead i want to pass the size for it

Comment: Then put the information you DO want to pass (ie the size) in the value.  @leftclickben said it right.  BTW  I would recommend that you pass the specific product ID rather than the size - much less prone to error.

Comment: So you want to make each product size an id? for an example 

ID   NAME

1    Size 12 blue Adidas shoe
2    size 14 blue Adidas shoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example for you <kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PtBJb/12/)**</kbd>.

Note how I added `<span>`s to be able to insert the texts at the position I want. I also added some `id`s to help with selecting the right `DOM` elements.

Here is the `JavaScript` based on `jQuery`.

```
// initially provide data
var shoeData = {
    12: 25,
    14: 30,
    16: 35
}

$(function () {    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // dynamically create the options in the select
        $.each(shoeData, function (key, value) {
            $("#size").append($("<option>", {
                "value": key,
                    "text": key + " size(£" + value + ")"
            }));
        });
        // display the initial data
        updateHandler();
    });    

    // register for update events on the input fields
    $("#size").on('change', updateHandler);
    $("#qty").on('input', updateHandler);
});

// handle update events (when an input field was changed)
function updateHandler() {
    // accumulate the data
    var value = $("#size").val();
    var quantity = $("#qty").val();
    var price = shoeData[value];
    var endPrice = price * quantity;

    // display the data
    $('#priceDisplay').html(price);
    $("#sizeDisplay").html(value);
    $("#totalDisplay").html(endPrice);
}
```

All you have to do is fill the shoeData object with data using `php` like so:

```
var shoeData = {
    12: <?php echo $row [ 'Start_Cost']; ?>,
    14: <?php echo "30"; ?>,
    16: <?php echo $priceForSize16; ?>,
}
```

When a customer changes the shoe size or quantity the total, price and shoe info is updated by simply writing the string into the "`html`" attribute of the appropriate `span`s.

Your `cart.php` will receive the form as expected - meaning you will get "`Qty`" and "`size`". You will have to look up the price in `PHP` based on the value from `$REQUEST["size"]` and then multiply it by the value of `$REQUEST["Qty"]` to get the total.

Answer (score 1):

First off you probably simply want to send the shoe size by supplying it to the option's value attribute. The text inside the option is only a label.

```
<option value="12">12 size</option>
```

Second and most important: You do never ever want the client to tell you what the price is!!! NEVER! If a hacker comes along he could easily submit the form with size set to 12 and price set to 0. You do not want to send those for free do you? Hack, might even have to refund him if he sends a negative value. So please modify your PHP script to calculate/lookup the price from an internal array or something. Or make sure you at least thoroughly validate the input.

---

To update the price you can use a [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to a php script that simply takes the shoe size and returns the price. 
Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QV8UZ/3/) for what I mean. You will have to replace the the ajax URL with a new php script of yours. Read up on the ajax documentation to figure out how to properly pass your input and output data. Before writing the data you could also then multiply the price with the quantity.

Comment: The only option where any user have the options to input any validate is the quantity of the item and it is set in the cart.php if the quantity  is below 0 it delete the item...

Comment: also if  value is 12 how will i calculate the price of the shoe size which needs to go into to the price...

Comment: _"I need to get the size and also the prize"_
Sounds like you would retrieve that info from the user form instead. 
Note that I updated my answer with some jquery example to hint you at how to dynamically get data.

Comment: The quanity, name, size and price are posted to cart.php and they cart.php gets it and blah blah.. i got all that working but just needs to get the price of the selected size and the size selected...